# Apache/PHP Detects JAR as ZIP

Tags: php, apache

Feel free to call me out on bad practice, but I'm verifying uploaded file MIME types on the server with `mime_content_type()`, and had planned to ignore the client filename and use my own filename with the MIME-appropriate extension.  Just as a test case (intended use case is with images), I uploaded a .jar file with Chrome, which correctly identifies the MIME type as application/x-java-archive, but my Apache/PHP server identifies the MIME as application/zip.  The client and server are on the same Fedora machine. Technically, jar and zip are mostly the same, but creating file extensions by MIME in this case will be incorrect.

Is that a Linux or FileInfo issue?  Maybe I'm missing a preparatory step to use the correct MIME database or the like?

Obligatory illustrative code sample:

Server-Side

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$client_mime = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$server_mime = mime_content_type($tmp_name);
$mimetest = array('client_mime' => $client_mime, 'server_mime' => $server_mime);
echo json_encode($mimetest);
?>
```

Client-Side JS

```
var formData = new FormData();
var $image   = $('#file')[0].files[0];
formData.append('image', $image);
var request = $.ajax({ method: "POST", url: "mimetest.php", data: formData, contentType: false, processData: false});
request.done(function(jsonData) { console.log('Received: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData)) });
```

Server Response (via Chrome DevTools)

```
Received: {"client_mime":"application/x-java-archive","server_mime":"application/zip"}
```

Comment: Do you get the same when you use `FileInfo`? http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php

Comment: unless I'm missing something, mime_content_type() is FileInfo (a function of that module)

Comment: No, the php manual states that `mime_content_type` is outdated and that it is recommended to use `FileInfo`. `mime_content_type` is a PHP core function.

Comment: Well, I see what you're suggesting. Using the other FileInfo functions finfo_*() to do the same job.  It was just my hope that there could be one function call instead of two or more. :)

Comment: Make a custom function ;)

Comment: Apache will abide the mime defined in the file refered by `TypesConfig`. I would start looking there.

Comment: A JAR file isn't just "similar to" a ZIP file, it *is* a ZIP file, just with particular contents. So in a sense, the result you're getting isn't wrong, just not very specific. Chrome is probably just cheating by looking at the filename - have you tried uploading after renaming it to .zip? Detecting JARs by inspecting the contents is (mostly) possible, but a lot more complex than the "magic number" (header) check most detectors use.